# Django unspecified error when deploying on Apache2

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, wagtail

Below is the error when I try deploy Django==3.2.12, wagtail==2.16.1, python 3.8.2, mod_wsgi 4.9 on a Debian 11 server. I have a full stack trace at the end.

```
class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
'property' object is not callable
```

When I run this on my local dev machine which is a Mac it works just fine. I [found](https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/kiKnMKVC7AY) someone with the exact same problem but no clarity about how it was resolved.

The resources I have been using to assist are [1](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/4.9.0/), [2](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html), [3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), [4](http://www.grimnes.no/blog/how-easily-deploy-wagtail-website/). I have tried installing mod_wsgi using pip and as well as from sources. Used various guides for Apache2 config. Upgraded from python 3.8 to 3.9 as well as downgraded to 3.7.

```
Create interpreter '0.0.0.0|'.
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.679710 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] mod_wsgi (pid=199764): Adding '/var/www/html/portal' to path.
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.680057 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] mod_wsgi (pid=199764): Adding  '/var/www/html/portal/portalvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages' to path.
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.689628 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy] mod_wsgi (pid=199764, process='saida-befree_portal', application='0.0.0.0|'): Loading Python script file '/var/www/html/portal/portal/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.705081 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy] mod_wsgi (pid=199764): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/portal/portal/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.713633 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy] mod_wsgi (pid=199764): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/portal/portal/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.713903 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.714017 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]   File "/var/www/html/portal/portal/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.714210 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.714304 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]   File "/var/www/html/portal/portalvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.717663 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.717837 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]   File "/var/www/html/portal/portalvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.718002 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]     from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.718072 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]   File "/var/www/html/portal/portalvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py", line 10, in <module>
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.718305 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]     from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.720700 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]   File "/var/www/html/portal/portalvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 362, in <module>
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.721066 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]     class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.721539 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy] TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:06.721610 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 199764:tid 139683953432320] [remote xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy]     'property' object is not callable
[Tue Mar 29 11:49:58.057546 2022] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 199765:tid 139683870795520] [client xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy] AH01382: Request header read timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so i did the following steps:

Remove the apache2 library by using the following command-
sudo apt-get remove python-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi

Then use the following command to install the correct library-
sudo apt-get install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

This solved my error.