# failed to exect wsgi.py (deploy django rest framework on apache2 with mod_wsgi)

Tags: python, django, apache, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy django rest framework on apache , and i did configure mod_wsgi with apache and did some changes to settings.py like static files and created virtualhost in apache , but im confusion right now , i don't know how i am suppose to access the api , when i try "curl 127.0.0.1:8001/django" i got the error below and when i try "curl 127.0.0.1:8001" i got client permission denied,.by the way I am using virtual environments,i install all the requirements on it , I guess the problem in execution wsgi.py but i don't know why .
here is the virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8001 _default_:8001>
  ServerAlias *
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject
  
  ServerAdmin yaz@gmail.com
    
   
    # Set the path to your Django projec
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject:/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject:/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias /django /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

    # Configure access to static files
    Alias /static/ /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/static
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
           Require all granted
        </Files>
        <Files "favicon.ico">
           Require all granted
        </Files>
  
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/logs/drfapp_error.log
    CustomLog /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/logs/drfapp_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is wsgi.py :

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

here is the settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.18.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-=z(3%l&3lrwvz16411c!-kjqaeb#@644o4$cd&go!w0ymi6(30'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['chatbotwQz.localhost']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'base',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.user_auth'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'chatbot',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

this is the error log

```
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220822 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000] mod_wsgi (pid=4299): Failed to exec Python script file '/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220857 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000] mod_wsgi (pid=4299): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220879 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220894 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]   File "/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220936 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220946 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]   File "/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220977 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.220986 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]   File "/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221024 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]     from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221033 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]   File "/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py", line 10, in <module>
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221092 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]     from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221101 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]   File "/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 362, in <module>
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221165 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]     class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221178 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000] TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
[Thu Jul 06 11:42:31.221183 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 4299] [remote 127.0.0.1:35000]     'property' object is not callable
and this is result of curl 127.0.0.1:8001
```

this result when i run curl 127.0.0.1:8001/django

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 yaz@gmail.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Your error is in wsgi.py file, please add it to your question

Comment: I found a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663729/django-unspecified-error-when-deploying-on-apache2

Comment: @StefanoLosi i already have  "libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3" and python3.7

Answer (score 0):

I looks that there is a repeated path in your WSGIDaemonProcess python-path.
Anyhow, the docs suggest to use the python-home directive pointed to the root of your venv:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/path/to/venv python-path=/path/to/mysite.com
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/