# Property Object is not callable with python 3.10 and django 4.1

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a django application on apache using [mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

However, I'm getting the following error when `wsgi.py` is running:

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/release/innovate-backend/src/rest_apis/rest_apis/apache/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py", line 10, in <module>
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 399, in <module>
class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
  TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
'property' object is not callable
```

Following is my `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os, sys

import time
import traceback
import signal
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
apache_configuration= os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
parent = os.path.dirname(workspace)

sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append(project)
sys.path.append(parent)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'rest_apis.apache.override'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like it might be the same problem as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71817875/202168